# Python - classes

Tags: python, class

I am starting to create game on the basis of LPHW ex43 and
 this is my - so far simple - code:

```
from sys import exit


class Engine():

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):

        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()

        while True:
            print "\n----------"
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

class Death():

    def enter(self):
        print "You are dead"
        exit(1)

class Castle():

    def enter(self):
        print "Welcome in my Castle"
        print "Choose between two paths: left or right"

        choice = raw_input(">")

        if choice == "left":
            return 'death'

        if choice == "right":
            return 'garden'

class Garden():

    def enter(self):
        print "Welcome..."
        exit(1)

class Map():

    scenes = {
    'castle': Castle(),
    'garden': Garden(),
    'death': Death()
    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        return Map.scenes.get(scene_name)

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

a_map = Map('castle')

a_game = Engine(a_map)

a_game.play()
```

My question - why am I not able to replace 
current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()

with 
current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(self.scene_map)

I don't understand why 'castle' is not found by method next_scene and is found by opening_scene. Once loop is executed next_scene will retrive 'garden' and 'death' from dictionary. Thanks in advance

Comment: `opening_scene` passes a different argument to `next_scene` than you did in your attempted replacement.

Comment: I think the reason might be that `self.scene_map` is a `Map`, but you want  `Map.scene` e.g.  `current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(self.scene_map.start_scene)`

Comment: Change your title to actually describe your specific issue.

Comment: You'll want to make sure all your classes define `__init__`. Otherwise nothing will happen when you create them.

Comment: @Woody1193 huh? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @AdamSmith My apologies, I thought he was trying to overload `enter`/`exit`. On closer inspection, his code makes sense. He should still be defining `__init__` though. Especially, if his objects are going to get more advanced

Comment: @Woody1193 why? `__init__` just defines what the object does when its instantiated. In this case: it's not supposed to do anything. And I think you're thinking of `__enter__` and `__exit__`. The double underscores are important! :)

Comment: @AdamSmith Correct again. Tbh, I'm so used to defining them I forgot that it wasn't required.

Answer (score 1):

`self.scene_map` is an object of type `Map`, while `Map.next_scene` expects an object of type `str`.

`Map.next_scene` queries a dictionary for the argument its given, but the dictionary only contains keys that are strings. `some_dict.get(nonexistent_key)` yields `None`, so you're getting `None` back as your `current_scene` in `a_game`

Comment: Thanks Adam. That being said, why current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene() works?

Comment: @AP_1984 because `Map.opening_scene` returns `self.next_scene(self.start_scene)`, not `self.next_scene(self)` like your proposed change would do.